# Ubuntu Phone Desktop mode without a dock

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was wondering...
Is there a way I can get to "Desktop mode" in Ubuntu phone without having a dock? (Even if it means that It'll stay that way permanently; Even if it requires USB Keyboard and mouse)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Since the first phone to come with convergence releases in october, it might come with Ubuntu Touch 15:10. So there's no desktope mode yet.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/06/first-ubuntu-phone-with-convergence-is-being-made-by-bq